# Bootstrap grid layout curiosity

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was wondering if with bootstrap it's possible to do something like this?
[image: Example Layout]

And when the size of the screen gets smaller, the small cubes would pass to one column, and then the big column on the right would go at the bottom of it all.

I'm creating a webApp with AngularJS and Laravel just for the curious ones.

Comment: you can definitely do that, but you need to write some javascript to detect the agent client and move the div containing the different containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with that:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="block block-lg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/Wwwoqy)**